# Passive voice (?) without 'be'

Tags: grammar

I know that question was already asked on this site, but I'm not sure in the answer I read about. So, the question is could passive voice exist without the verb 'be'? Here are examples:

> 1. Mission is accomplished.
> 2. The usual "mission accomplished" message.

In the first case, we have a passive voice. In second, I believe, too. But which of them is right? I guess both are.

P.S. I read about this that this is called 'middle voice'. And something about verbs we can use in a passive voice without 'be', regardless I would like to get an answer.

Comment: Partly it's just "headline English" (sometimes called "telegraphic"), where non-critical words are left out.  Consider that with old telegrams you paid by the word.

Comment: This is not a _middle voice_ (alternatively called the _mediopassive_ or _activo-passive_), an example of which is _This book reads well._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, the present participle and the past participle have adjectival properties:

The running man = the man **who runs/is running** - The present participle expresses an active verb.

The beaten man = the man who **was/has been beaten** - the past participle expressed a passive form.

Mission **accomplished** is therefore passive = the mission **has been** accomplished.